# Redirect command output without overwriting

Tags: bash

I do have a command like this:

```
 grep pattern file > result && head -n 1 file >> result
```

In which I use `grep` to extract the specific pattern and `head` to extract the headline.

Is it possible to simplify my command ? For example to redirect the output from `grep`?

If I am using this:

```
 head -n 1 file > result <<(grep pattern file)
```

I get an error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token ('`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a command group to combine the standard output of your two commands:

```
{ grep pattern file && head -1 file; } > result
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you need this:

```
grep pattern file | head -n 1 file >> result
```

Send stdout from grep by pipe to head and then append into file result.
If you don't want/need it in file result, only on screen, you can use:

```
grep pattern file | head -n 1 file
```

I hope I've helped.

Comment: I want to extract pattern from file and headline from the same file. Not the headline of the extracted pattern.

Comment: Ok, then maybe the solution will be: `grep pattern file >> result && head -n 1 file >> result` , or?

Comment: This is what I am already using and I want to simplify this two part command.